# how to disable the alter panel caused by NSAlert automatic?

Tags: cocoa

I find a interest thing: when I used a Browse button to choose a file , if the file have exist
, the NSAlert will cause a alter panel automatic, but I want to make this by my self , how to disable the NSAlert's alter panel automatic? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement the -panel:userEnteredFilename:confirmed: delegate method. Returning nil will suppress the standard panel. However, I warn you that you better have a good reason for overriding it otherwise there will be plenty of puzzled/irritated users!